# Using Promises upon different parts of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a program that has as main object a object called GLOB,.

In the first phase of the program , I need to get all the files in a folder using an async function and assign the result to the files property, so I'm using a Promise:

```
GLOB.files = new Promise (resolve, reject) {

  AsyncFunc(args, function(result) {
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

Then, in older phases, I need access the GLOB files, but I need make some CPU intensive work, so I'm using async.eachLimit to limit the number of concurrencies, because of this, the whole GLOB will become a Promise:

```
new Promise (resolve, reject) {

   GLOB.files.then(function(files) {

     var temporary1 = [];
     var temporary2 = [];

     async.eachLimit(files, 5, function(file, callback) {

       // do something here
       //
       // temporary1.push(file); or temporary2.push(file);


     }, function(error, files) {

       // Work with temporary1 and temporary2 variable here, delete some unnecessary pieces and then reassign it to GLOB.files;

       // REASSIGN GLOB.files
       GLOB.files = temporary1.concat(temporary2);

       // resolve passing the GLOB
       resolve(GLOB);
     });

   });
}
```

Now to be able to access everything I need call GLOB.then, because it's a Promise.

```
GLOB.then(function(GLOB) {

   // everything ok! :)

});
```

Everything is working ok, I'm not having any problem, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: why `mapLimit` and not `Promise.all` ?

Comment: no, but you said that you are feeling you are doing something wrong, in my eyes Promise.all seems to be the correct choice, if your feeling is related to performance.

Comment: I made i mistake, i'm using each-limit, not map-limit, sorry. I'm using each-limit because when the loops ends, before reassign the GLOB.files i'm doing some extra work, do i have this option with Promise.all?/

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Check my updated in the body question please?

Comment: _"Everything is working ok, i'm not having any problem, but i feel like i'm doing something wrong..."_ Not certain what Question is?

Comment: Sorry. My question is: Is it normal what i'm doing? Seems very strange make a property of a object a Promise, then the whole object.

Comment: @D_REIS Not sure what definition of "normal" is. Though consider `jQuery.ajax()`, which wraps `XMLHttpRequest()` in `jQuery.Deferred()` returning a jQuery promise object. If "Everything is working ok" at your approach, why create an issue based on a sense that what you are achieving is "strange"?

Comment: Because i don't have much experience with Promises, maybe i shoudn't do what i am doing.